# How to extract nested type

Tags: typescript

How do I extract the type of a nested property? For example say I have this type:

```
type Example = {
   nested: string,  // how do I infer string here
   other: string
}
```

Such that I can extract out 'string' from Example.nested?

I have `type myType = Pick<Example, "nested">` and that provides `{ nested: string }`, but I want to infer the type of the property 'nested' (string, in this example) on that object.

Comment: `Example["nested"]`

Comment: It's called a "[lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types)" or "indexed access type"

Comment: Oh, that's it, thanks @jcalz. If you submit this as an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You want to use a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) (also called an "indexed access type") which uses the square bracket syntax.

That is,

```
type myType = Example["nested"] // string
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDbQLxQN4CgpQB2EAzsBACYBcUZATgJaEDmA3PlAPbAAWEdNekza4Avu1yhIUJCAAq4TLEQp0AbQBExMpQ0BdVlAD0R2sEYtcQA)

Comment: What if it's an optional key?

Comment: FYI: If the nested type is an array and you want the type of an entry in the array, the syntax is `Example["nested"][0]`.

Comment: If a property in between the access chain is optional, you can make it NonNullable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69110671/1189762