# How to use an indexed access type for children of an optional property?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type like:

```
type Person = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  contact: {
    type: string;
    value: string;
  }[];
};
```

If I want the type of an element of the `contact` array, I can use an indexed access type like:

```
type Contact = User['contact'][number];

// same as type Contact = { type: string; value: string };
```

In essence, "the type at a numeric index of the `contacts` array", and would also work for a nested object.

However, if that is an optional parameter such as:

```
type Person = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  contact?: {
    type: string;
    value: string;
  }[];
};
```

This (validly) reports an error of:

```
Type '{ type: string; value: string; }[] | undefined' has no matching index signature for type 'number'.ts(2537)
```

How can I "null check" within the type alias to get a nested type?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update**

`NonNullable<T>` will remove `undefined` and `null` from its type parameter.

```js
type Contact = NonNullable<User['contact']> // almost the same as the next type, but also excludes `null` from the union.
type Contact = Exclude<User['contact'], undefined>[number];
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype

**Older answer**

You can `Exclude` types when you need to drill down more.

```js
type Contact = Exclude<User['contact'], undefined>[number];
```

The docs aren't particularly stable around the subject, but https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html is the current link.

Comment: Was afraid it would be something like this... Really wish we could use something like `User['contact']![number]`.

Comment: @EricHaynes I think it'd be nice to allow both non-null assertions and `?.` for type level drilling. There might already be an issue in Typescript's GitHub repo for it even.

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't be easier and more readable to just type `contact` separately?

```
type Person = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  contact?: PersonContact[];
};

type PersonContact = {
  type: string;
  value: string;
};
```

Comment: It's not always a type you control. And frankly, no, turning structured data into a series of flat objects is far less readable. Being able to define a type that looks exactly like the data it describes is one of the more underrated features of Typescript. You don't have to hunt around in a bunch of different types to try to infer the actual shape. If the inner type is valid on its own, then promoting it to a first class type is valid. But e.g. if you only need to refer to it in some corner case of a builder function, preserving the model structure is preferable.