# How do I extract the type of a particular property in a given type?

Tags: typescript

So let's say I have a type Foo defined as:

```
type Foo = {
    bar: string;
    xxx: {
        abc: string;
        def: number;
    };
};
```

How do I extract the type of my property `xxx` to define let's say a parameter of the same shape as the `xxx` property of my Foo type?

I've come up with this dirty hack, but I'm sure there has to be a proper way? I can't seem to find it in the documentation though!

```
const _ = "anything" as unknown as Foo;
type XXXType = typeof _.xxx;
```

Comment: @TobiasS. It does indeed, thank you very much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69110544/typescript-how-to-use-an-indexed-access-type-for-children-of-an-optional-proper

this one also helped!