# How to declare a TypeScript type as the object type in an array of objects from another interface?

Tags: typescript

I have this generated interface:

```
export interface StaticPageLeftMenuV1 {
    id: string
    status: 'draft' | 'published'
    environments: ('dev' | 'staging' | 'production')[]
    created_by?: string | User
    last_modified_by?: string | User
    list?: {
        header?: string
        items?: {
            relation?: {
                value: string | StaticPageV1
                relationTo: 'static-page-v1'
            }
            custom_link_text?: string
            custom_link_url?: string
            custom_link_color?: string
            id?: string
        }[]
        id?: string
    }[]
}
```

How can I declare a type of item, as found in `obj.list[0].items[0]`

You can get list easily enough with :

```
type List = StaticPageLeftMenuV1['list']
```

Which is an array, but I can't figure out how to get the type of the object.

This doesn't work:

```
type Item = StaticPageLeftMenuV1['list'][0]['items'][0]
```

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69110544/3001761.

Comment: `type Item = Required<Required<StaticPageLeftMenuV1>['list'][number]>['items'][number]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it like this:

```
type List = Required<StaticPageLeftMenuV1>['list'][number]
type Item = Required<List>['items'][number]
```